# Understanding a question about gradient descent flow

Tags: optimization, image-processing, gradient-descent

I'm working on the following image processing problem.

> If $I$ is an $m\times n$ real valued matrix (an image), and $\overset{\rightharpoonup}{I}$ is a vector with each $I_{i,j}$ as components, and $I_0$ is the original noisy image.  We define
>   $$E(\overset{\rightharpoonup}{I}) = \sum_{i=0}^m \sum_{j=0}^n \sqrt{(I_{i+1,j} - I_{i,j})^2 + (I_{i,j+1} - I_{i,j})^2 + \epsilon^2} + \lambda \sum_{i=0}^m \sum_{j=0}^n (I_{i,j} - (I_0)_{i,j})^2 $$
>   Find $\partial E / \partial I_{i,j}$ and find the gradient descent flow $(I_t)_{i,j}$.

This seems incomprehensible to me.  I'm not looking for the answer, but I'm curious if someone could help me parse this question.  This is what I'm thinking so far:

This equation is a discretization of the following:

$$ \iint_R |\nabla I|\, \mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y + \lambda \iint_R (I - I_0)^2\, \mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y$$

But I'm thrown off by the notation in $\partial E / \partial I_{i,j}$.  Should I literally take the partial derivative of the above equation with respect to $I_{i+1}$?  I really appreciate your input.

Comment: Ideally, the energy functional would be written in terms of matrices. For example, the regularization term $$\sum_{i=0}^m \sum_{j=0}^n (I_{i,j} - (I_0)_{i,j})^2$$ is the squared Frobenius norm of the difference of two matrices (whose derivative is easy).

Comment: Why start the summations at $i, j = 0$?